# How to make buttons like in example using python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python-telegram-bot

[Nice telegrm bot's menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqHX9.png)

I'm found an interesting menu on Telegram's @ShopBot 
So right how i want to make menu for my bot, just like this one.

Where coud i find code examples or tutrorals how to make checkbox-like buttons like in this menu using python-telegram-bot framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])
def menu(m):

  cid = m.chat.id

  menuKeyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
  menuKeyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Button1', callback_data='button1'),
           types.InlineKeyboardButton('Button2', callback_data='button2'))

  bot.send_message(cid, "Menu", reply_markup=menuKeyboard)
```